# xUnit IClassFixture is not run at every test

Tags: xunit

Per the documentation for the IClassFixture https://xunit.net/docs/shared-context, it says

*"Just before the first tests in MyDatabaseTests is run, xUnit.net will create an instance of DatabaseFixture. For each test, it will create a new instance of MyDatabaseTests, and pass the shared instance of DatabaseFixture to the constructor."*

I stare hard at the "For each test" part. Because, it does only calls the inherited fixture once, at least in my code.

```
   public class TransportSequenceResourceAggregateServiceTests : IClassFixture<TransportSequenceResourceAggregateServiceFixture>
{
    private TransportSequenceResourceAggregateServiceFixture fixture;
    public TransportSequenceResourceAggregateServiceTests(TransportSequenceResourceAggregateServiceFixture fixture)
    {
        this.fixture = fixture;
    }

    [Fact]
    public void If_No_Aggregate_Exist_Return_Null()
    {
        var sut = fixture.transportSequenceResourceAggregateService;

        var aggrate = sut.Get("some_new_resource");

        Assert.True(aggrate == null);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void If_Resource_Does_Not_Exists_Create_New_Aggreagate()
    {
        var sut = fixture.transportSequenceResourceAggregateService;

        var aggrate = sut.Create("some_new_resource");

        Assert.True(aggrate.ResourcePosition == null);
        Assert.True(aggrate.TransportSequences == null);
    }
```

But maybe I am reading it wrong ?

Is it not supposed to create a new fixture every time a test is being run ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that `MyDatabaseTests` is your test class and `DatabaseFixture` is instance of the class you want instantiate once and pass to every test

> **Just before the first tests** in MyDatabaseTests is run, xUnit.net will
>   **create an instance of DatabaseFixture**.

Then

> For each test, it will create a new instance of MyDatabaseTests, and
>   pass the shared instance of DatabaseFixture to the constructor

Would be: for each test xUnit create new instance of test class  and pass already created instance of fixture

Another approach

MyDatabaseTests => TransportSequenceResourceAggregateServiceTests
DatabaseFixture => TransportSequenceResourceAggregateServiceFixture

So fixture will be created only once.

Comment: I have created DatabaseFixture and on debugging it, found out that the dispose method is called on every test case completion. so how can you say that fixture is created only once.
Also, even if your point is correct, how does that completes the requirement of sharing the instance...because when the new instance of test class is created for every test method...every object would be assigned?